# How can I run a timer in C++ without interfering with my other code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, time, sprite, difference

I tried to make a cmd terminal game using ANSI sequences in C++ but I'm stuck now. In my game a character moves at a constant speed steadily while the enemies move at speeds lover than that. Like, some fast and some slow. How can I set a timer for all? Setting a timer pauses the whole execution. I want a timer to be set only for a specific sprite. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you familiar with multithreaded programs and threads in general?

Comment: Normally, in a game, you have an update loop and a delta-time between update-frames, so you'd just have to multiply an entity's speed with the delta-time and modify the position by that value. Timers would not be necessary with such a solution

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well that way I would've to use a lot of threading in my code. I was told that such simple applications shouldn't use a lot of threading. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: @UnholySheep To be honest, I am doing the game in the command terminal. I have to move the characters manually rather than depending on another library or game engine. I don't see how this can be done without a timeout, such as the sleep() function from the <windows.h> header.

Comment: You don't need any library or engine to make an update loop. That can be as simple as a `while(true)` with keeping a timestamp between iterations (or using the Windows message loop)

Answer (score 1):

A common solution is to use an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (such as [Asio C++ Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), [libevent](https://libevent.org/), [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv)), where you register a callback for timer expiry and the event loop manages timers (and other events) and invokes your callback on timer expiry. See [this code example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html).

A better new option is to use coroutines, if available, [Asio C++ Library can do that](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.asio-coroutines). Coroutines obviate the need to use callbacks, which makes the code simpler.

Under the hood, all these libraries invoke a platform-specific event demultiplexing function, such as `select`/`epoll_wait`. The event loop libraries *conceptually* sort all timer expirations and wait till the earliest one - the timeout argument to `select`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. But I am making my game in the windows cmd terminal, without using any other libraries other than the basic <vector>, <string>, <iostream>, <cstdlib> and <windows.h>  I tried to think of a way around this using the sleep() function from the windows.h module but the time freeze is universal rather than for a single ASCII sprite (an instance of a 2D class that I had created). Would storing the initial time in a variable and comparing it with every iteration be a plausible approach? That way, I could make it work.

Comment: @ If you insist on not using libraries, then you must learn how these libraries manage timers and implement them on your own. The last paragraph in my answer explains how to manage multiple timers.